# Denied directory but not subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Full path

```
"GET /2008/10/page/2/Promosi-Jimat-Jimat-Parkson HTTP/1.1" 200 67948 "-"
```

Directory

```
/2009/09/
/2009/09/
/2008/05/
/2006/12/
```

Is it possible i denied public from access folder but not on full path?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check for

```
Options -Indexes
```

in your .htaccess file.

If it is there, change it to

```
Options Indexes
```

or remove it.